# Getting ENOBUFS in a loop of http requests node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Some background:
What I do is receive a CSV file with some ids from the client.
I run on the file and for each ID I make need to make a rest query that is followed by another rest query.

This thing works fine when I do it for 1,000 to ~ 5,000 ids but after that most of my responses at the logs are errors instead of "200".

The error is:

```
[Error: connect ENOBUFS XX.XX.XX.XXX:8080 - Local (undefined:undefined)]
  code: 'ENOBUFS',
  errno: 'ENOBUFS',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'XX.XX.XX.XXX',
  port: 8080
```

What I saw on similar questions a suggestion to use `async.eachOfLimit` and that way to make a small amount of requests but for some it doesn't continue after the first iteration.
http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOfLimit - The documentation if the module.

Simple code illustration:

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
.
.
.
    async.eachOfLimit(ids,100, CheckAndUpdate);
});

function CheckAndUpdate(DirtyId, callback){
   request({
     uri:  "http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8080/rest/getTureIDs" + DirtyId, ",
     json: true
   }, function(err, res, data) {
     if (err) {
       console.log('Error:', err);
     } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
       console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
     } else {
       if (data["TrueIDs"].length > 0){
         for (var index in data["TrueIDs"]){
           var fetchedID = data["TrueIDs"][index]["id"];
           UpdateSomethingForID(fetchedID);
         }
       }
     }
   });
}

function UpdateSomethingForID(ID, callback){
    request({
      uri:  "http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8080/rest/SetTouchedToday/" + ID,
      json: true
    }, function(err, res, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
      } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
      } else {
        console.log("Great success");
      }
    });
  }
```

So the questions is:
How can I "spam" the request in a more proper way to avoid the ENOBUFS? 
Or what am I doing wrong with the `eachOfLimit`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not calling the callback at all.

Comment: I don't have anything that needs to be done there.  I made a test with a callback that contained only console.log("nothing") and still didn't work but the callbacks were printed for 1 iteration...

Comment: You definitely do DDoS attack to your server!

Comment: _"I don't have anything that needs to be done there"_. Yes, you do: after each iteration, you have to call `callback`.

Comment: As I said, even with a callback for the sake of it this didn't work. Ill try again and ill :)

Comment: Ok, now after I tried for testing eachOfLimit just to do console.log(key) I get `Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.  will try to figure out a better solution for myself, probably my array is to big...(~26k)